# How to select the last id of grouped selected names in Codeigniter?

Tags: php

```
function retrieve_income_types(){
    $this->db->where('active','1');
            $this->db->group_by('Income_Type_Name');        
            $this->db->order_by('Income_Type_ID', 'desc');
    return $this->db->get('Income_Types')->result();
}
```

this is my model
it returns the smallest id of grouped names

Comment: You can order it so the smallest id is at the the top. Then use [TOP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) SQL code to select only the top record. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: How I can write it in Codeigniter ??

Comment: I would ask how you can make this SQL query, this makes to question more general. If that works, it will also work in Codeigniter :) I, however, do not know how to make this query. Also write the information you gave me in the question :)